# search position behind last preg_match_all result

Tags: preg-match-all

i need the **first position behind last match**. because i want search in content behind my regex_match_all (in this example `,sometingBehind`) .

that's probably not possible (out of the box) to get from [preg-match-all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

### source

`start "settings":{"PlayerData":[{"Name":"m (1196)","Civ":"ptol","Team":0,"AI":f,"c":{"r":21,"g":55,"b":149}},{"Name":"s (898)","Civ":"p","Team":0,"AI":false,"c":{"r":150,"g":20,"b":20}},sometingBehind`

### my preg_match_all

```
    preg_match_all('/Name":"([^"(]+)(?:\((\d*)\))?([^"]*)","Civ":"([^"]+)",.*?"Team":(\d+)/'
        , $file_content
        , $matches
        , PREG_SET_ORDER
        , 0);
    var_dump($matches);
```

### my $matches are as expected (missing the endPos)

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(46) "Name":"m (1196)","Civ":"ptol","Team":0"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "m "
    [2]=>
    string(4) "1196"
    [3]=>
    string(0) ""
    [4]=>
    string(4) "ptol"
    [5]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(40) "Name":"s (898)","Civ":"ptol","Team":0"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "s "
    [2]=>
    string(3) "898"
    [3]=>
    string(0) ""
    [4]=>
    string(4) "ptol"
    [5]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the first position after the `0` ? https://regex101.com/r/MFb5ou/1

Comment: i want search in the rest source= `,sometingBehind`

Comment: Is the part of the string where you want to get a match json?

Comment: source is not clean json

Comment: In the current pattern there are no anchors, and you get all the multiple group values. But is there any logic to get to the position at `,somethingBehind`? You might do it like this, but there can be any nested structures in between https://regex101.com/r/KBR8JU/1/

Comment: For reasons of performance, I want to know the first position of my next search with the next search. That is the end of the last search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

searching and get the contentBehind the search.

#### Using PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE

If this flag is passed, for every occurring match the appendant string offset (in bytes) will also be returned.

#### using array_key_last

array_key_last returns last key of array if the array is not empty; NULL otherwise.

needs (PHP 7 >= 7.3.0, PHP 8)

```php
preg_match_all('/Name":"([^"(]+)(?:\((\d*)\))?([^"]*)","Civ":"([^"]+)",.*?"Team":(\d+)/'
    , $file_content
    , $matches
    , PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE
    , 0);

$contentBehind = getContentBehind($matches, $file_content);
echo contentBehind; # ,sometingBehind in this example

/**
 * @param $matches
 * @param $file_content
 * using array_key_last (PHP 7 >= 7.3.0, PHP 8)
 * @return string contentBehind
 */
function getContentBehind($matches, $file_content, $maxLength=100){
    $last1ArrayValue = $matches[array_key_last($matches)];
    $last2ArrayValue = $last1ArrayValue[array_key_last($last1ArrayValue)];
    $lastKey = array_key_last($last2ArrayValue);
    $lastPos = $last2ArrayValue[$lastKey];
    $posBehindLastSearch = $lastPos + $last1ArrayValue[array_key_last($last1ArrayValue) - 1][$lastKey - 1];
    $contentBehind = substr($file_content, $posBehindLastSearch, $maxLength);
    return $contentBehind;
}
```